# How do I export internals to a test project in F#?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

In C# you can create use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute in AssemblyInfo.c to give a test project access to a project's internals, so you can unit test parts of your project that you don't want to make public.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestProject")]
```

I cannot discover an equivalent solution in F#, or even discover how to add an attribute to an assembly at all. Is there a solution (or an equivalent workaround) and if so what is it?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `[<assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestProject")>] do()` in one of your modules?

Answer (score 20):

Jeff Mercado's solution to getting an assembly attribute (which I'd never seen before) lead to the following solution for my problem. Thanks Jeff!

```ml
module AssemblyInfo

open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestProject")>]
do()
```

Answer (score 6):

Put this into your fsproj file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
     <_Parameter1>$(AssemblyName).Tests</_Parameter1>
   </AssemblyAttribute>
   <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
     <_Parameter1>DynamicProxyGenAssembly2</_Parameter1>
   </AssemblyAttribute>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Note that the entry for DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 is only needed if Moq is used.

Comment: unfortunately this will not work with JetBrains Rider